# Jooq codegen doesn't generate classes

Tags: java, jooq

Jooq doesn't generate classes. I use gradle plugin https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin with postgresql 42.2.24. What is my problem?  This is my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.7'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'nu.studer.jooq' version '6.0.1'
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq'

    implementation 'org.jooq:jooq-meta:3.15.1'
    implementation 'org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.15.1'
    implementation 'org.jooq:jooq:3.15.1'


    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    jooqGenerator 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.24'
}

jooq {
    version = '3.15.1'
    edition = nu.studer.gradle.jooq.JooqEdition.OSS
    configurations {
        main {
            generationTool {
                logging = org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Logging.WARN
                jdbc {
                    driver = 'org.postgresql.Driver'
                    url = 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postman'
                    user = 'postgres'
                    password = ''
                }
                generator {
                    name = 'org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGenerator'
                    strategy {
                        name = 'org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGeneratorStrategy'
                    }
                    database {
                        name = 'org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase'
                        inputSchema = 'public'
                        includes = '.*'
                        excludes = ''
                    }
                    target {
                        packageName = 'com.sample'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output
Task :generateJooq

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
1 actionable task: 1 executed

Comment: I've tried as you did and this works fine for me. I see all the generated classes under build\generated-src\jooq

Comment: @SimonMartinelli
 I have directories being created, but no classes and packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes were generated in a different directory, since there was a directory with a non-English name in the path